# What does this phrase mean? "Good at the moment, bad in the long run"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

What does the following mean and how could it be used?

> Good at the moment, bad in the long run?

Comment: You've got to be more specific than that as there are many words in English that would fit that description. The adjective *temporary* would probably be one the most generic ones. Something that's temporarily good is going to be good for a certain period of time, but later it will probably become bad.

Comment: @Coo I think you misread the question: As I read it, the OP does not seek a word to replace the phrase, but rather asks what the expression means. I've edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word to describe such situations is **short-sighted**.

> To have converted so many parking spots to all-day meters may have
>   raised revenues for the municipal coffers and made commuters happy, but now there's less space for shoppers to park for brief amounts of time, and small businesses in town are seeing a drop in the number of customers. The decision was
>   **short-sighted**.

Answer (score 1):

We can use that to say that something is temporarily good, but eventually will be negative.

An example might be someone who uses a lot of alcohol or drugs to feel pleasure. It may feel good at the moment, but will probably cause more problems than it's worth: for example, someone might get hurt trying to drive or walk, etc. Or someone might get sick and feel terrible the next day. Someone could keep using the substance and become addicted, etc.

The key to answering your question is probably understanding the meaning of *in/over the long run* which means

> not immediately but at some time in the future

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/in-the-long-run-term